# Sum of Products

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the smallest upper bound for the following:
\begin{eqnarray*}
A\left(N\right):=\max_{a_{1}a_{2},...,a_{N}\in\left[0,1\right]}\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}^{1/2}\prod_{s=1}^{n-1}\left(1-a_{s}\right)^{1/2}
\end{eqnarray*}
where empty product is one? I can only get $A\left(N\right)\leq C\ln N$
for some $C<\infty$. For example, let $a_{n}=1/\left(2n\right)^{2}$,
then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\\1>\prod_{s=1}^{n-1}\left(1-a_{s}\right)^{1/2} & > & \prod_{s=1}^{\infty}\left(1-a_{s}\right)^{1/2}\\
 & = & (2/\pi)^{1/2}
\end{eqnarray*}
using the formula 
\begin{eqnarray*}\sin\left(\pi x\right)=\pi x\prod_{s=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{s}\right)^{2}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Then, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
A\left(N\right) & < & \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2n}\\
 & \leq & \ln N.
\end{eqnarray*}
Does any other sequence $a_{1}a_{2},...,a_{N}\in\left[0,1\right]$
exist such that the bound is larger than $O\left(\ln N\right)$?

Comment: Got something from my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n=\Theta(n^{-1-c})$ with $c\gt0$ then $A(N)=\Theta(N^{1/2-c/2})$.

Comment: If $c=0$ in your example,$A(N)\asymp n^{-1}$, I mean two sides are of the same order of magnitude:  $a_{s}=b/x$,
$b\in\left(0,1\right)$, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
1>\prod_{s=1}^{n-1}\left(1-a_{s}\right)^{1/2} & = & \exp\left\{ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}\ln\left(1-a_{s}\right)\right\} >\exp\left\{ \frac{1}{2}\int_{2}^{\infty}\ln\left(1-\frac{b}{x}\right)dx\right\} \\
 & > & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
then $A\left(N\right)\asymp\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^{1/2}\asymp N^{1/2}$.
Can one find a $c<0$ and get a bigger growth
rate, e.g. $A\left(N\right)\asymp N^{\left(1+c\right)/2}$?

Comment: Except that the integral in your comment diverges. Please stick to my answer, where $c\gt0$ for a reason.

Comment: Thank you, I see now that my argument is wrong. For my purposes I need to to rule out $c=0$: I need to show that $c>0$ is the only possibility. Can you give me a hint on how to show that one must have $c>0$? Can I use the integral but with different limits to get an upper bound and show that this goes to zero? Is there a simpler argument?

Comment: "For my purposes I need to to rule out c=0" I do not understand, there is no $c$ in your question so why would you need to rule out $c=0$, and in which sense? It seems to me that you asked a question, that I answered it, and that now you are embarking on something different...

Comment: Sorry, can you give me a hint on how to show your original answer?

Comment: And now you completely shift the subject... Please just explain which part of the implication in my answer is causing you trouble.

Comment: Given my initial question, I take that in your first question you
mean that if $a_{n}\asymp n^{-1-c}$ then $A\left(N\right)\asymp n^{\left(1-c\right)/2}$
for $c>0$. I have troubles bounding $\prod_{s=1}^{n-1}\left(1-a_{s}\right)^{1/2}$
from below with such choice of $a_{n}$.

Comment: "My first question"? I have no question (and what you write is not what I mean but what I **state**, just read). For the sequences $(a_n)$ I suggest, the series $\sum\limits_na_n$ converges hence indeed the infinite product $\prod\limits_s(1-a_s)^{1/2}$ is positive.